# How can I query a json file in Seq?

Tags: logging, seq

I'm completely new in logging but familiar in SQL queries. I'm now experimenting with Serilog and [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq). I managed to make JSON lines log file with Serilog and could import the file into Seq by the `seqcli ingest -i` command. I can query my stream but in a very limited way. E.g.

```
select * from stream
```

works as shown on the screenshot below (the example file is Seq's own log):

[image]

I can also query the @Timestamp, @Arrived and @Data colums as

```
select @Timestamp, @Arrived, @Data from stream
```

but I don't know how can I reach the properties inside @Data. I expect something like

```
select @Timestamp, @Arrived, @Data.@mt.@mt.UserId from stream
```

but this doesn't work. How can I list for example the @Data.@mt.@mt.UserId values?

### UPDATE

Interesting that Seq shows something else than the original content of the file. This part:
[image]
looks in the original file simply as this:

> {"@t":"2022-03-30T14:24:49.0999009Z","@mt":"Creating default workspace for {UserId}","UserId":"user-admin"}

so, regarding this, I would expect

```
select @mt.UserId from stream
```

or some similar query work.

Comment: Writing from Serilog directly to Seq using `WriteTo.Seq()` from https://github.com/datalust/serilog-sinks-seq is a much better experience if you have that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing using `seqcli ingest`, you need to specify `--json`, e.g.:

```
seqcli ingest -i ./some.log --json
```